# Apache Camel Ldap filter Operation is not working

Tags: java, ldap, apache-camel

I'm currently working on an Apache Camel project and I'm having trouble using the LDAP component for query operations. I'm using Apache Camel version 3.20.4 and the Spring Boot starter.

I have followed the documentation and configured the LDAP component in my code.
But it is giving me an error as "Caused by: javax.naming.directory.InvalidSearchFilterException: Empty filter; remaining name 'ou=users,dc=example,dc=com'".

Following are maven dependencies

1. apache-camel-core- version 3.20.4
2. apache-camel-ldap -version 3.20.4

Following is code which I am trying

```
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        getContext().setAllowUseOriginalMessage(true);
        DirContext dirContext = createLdapConnection();
        getContext().getRegistry().bind("ldapConnection", dirContext);


        from("direct:start")
                .log("LDAP Component Started")
                .to("ldap:ldapConnection?base=ou=users,dc=example,dc=com&scope=subtree")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    String result = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                    System.out.println(result);
                });
    }
    private static DirContext createLdapConnection() throws NamingException {
        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:10389");
        env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.sun.jndi.url");
        env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=admin,ou=system");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        return new InitialDirContext(env);
    }
```

I tried another

```
.to("ldap:ldapConnection?base=ou=users,dc=example,dc=com&filter=(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)")
```

Could anyone please guide me on how to properly use the Apache Camel LDAP component or Spring LDAP for query operations? Are there any additional configuration settings or considerations that I might be missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to escape the '=' sign with '%3D' , otherwise Camel will use it as separator for the component params:
"ldap:ldapConnection?base=ou%3Dusers,dc%3Dexample,..."